# Cannot return a String in Kotlin when don't "private"

Tags: kotlin

Why it error when i make userName is public:

> Error:(2, 5) Kotlin: Platform declaration clash: The following
>   declarations have the same JVM signature
>   (getUserName()Ljava/lang/String;):
>       fun (): String defined in User
>       fun getUserName(): String defined in User
>
> Error:(4, 5) Kotlin: Platform declaration clash: The following declarations have the same
>   JVM signature (getUserName()Ljava/lang/String;):
>       fun (): String defined in User
>       fun getUserName(): String defined in User

But i make userName is private is working fine

```
 class User{
            /*private*/ var userName: String = "Emily"

            fun getUserName(): String{
                return userName
            }
        }

        fun main(args: Array<String>){
            val User = User()
            print(User.getUserName())
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you define `var userName` you are [really defining a property](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/properties.html), not just a field. Along with the property comes an implicit `getUserName()` and `setUserName()` method. By adding your own `getUserName()`, you are shadowing the one Kotlin is creating for you automatically.

You can safely drop your `getUserName()` and the make your field non-private and it should work fine. The idiomatic way to write your code would be something like this:

```
class User {
    var userName: String = "Emily"
}

fun main(args: Array<String>){
    val user = User()    // Note changed val from User to user.
    print(user.userName) // Note, this really calls the getter
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 4):

By making your `userName` property `public`, Kotlin will create corresponding `getUserName()` and `setUserName()` functions for you.  When it does this, writing your own `getUserName()` is redundant - the same function with the same signature is effectively present twice - and the compiler won't allow it.

If you want the `userName` field to be a public property (with a generated getter and setter), then you can't also write the getter yourself. This would be adequate:

```
var userName: String = "Emily"
```

If you wanted `userName` to have a `public` getter and a `private` setter (which seems like what you intended), this is the Kotlin way to do that:

```
var userName: String = "Emily"
    private set
```

And finally, you could still create custom accessors on a property (e.g., if you wanted extra logic, such as to return it lowercased). The Kotlin way to do that looks like this:

```
private var _userName: String = "Emily"
var userName: String
    get() = _userName.toLowerCase()
    set(value) { _userName = value }
```

Also, note that the way you access the property is different depending on whether you're accessing it from Kotlin or Java.  From Kotlin, you just write `user.userName`, but in Java, you'd write `user.getUserName()`.

Comment: oh. Thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

In Kotlin, a setter and getter is being created for every property (unless visibility prohibits it), e.g. for your `userName` which happens to be named exactly like the one you provided in addition: `getUserName()`. The result is a name clash. Note that for `var`, also setters are generated. Use `val` for read-only properties.

Actually, you don't need explicit getters like this. Simply do:

```
class User{
    /*private*/ var userName: String = "Emily"
}

//use property syntax
val user = User()
print(user.userName)
```

Comment: I understand. Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

I just want to add more about `private` field. When you declare a field with `private` modifier, Kotlin won't generate getter/setter

```
class User {

    private var userName = "Na"

    fun getUserName(): String {
        return userName;
    }

    fun setUserName(v: String) {
        userName = v
    }

}
```

And when you declare above methods (getter and setter) then these are treated as **User Defined** methods.

Comment: @halfer for next posts i will keep that in mind and will try to edit my previous posts. Thanks.